# Where can I download a ascmd.exe?

Tags: command-line, ssas, olap, mdx, ascmd

I need to execute MDX query from command line (MS AS 2005). I have heard, that there is a program named ascmd, which can do this. Unfortunately, when I went to codeplex page I found that page supposed to deliver an ascmd doesn't work. Please help if you know any other page, where I can download ascmd or any other program executing MDX in command line. Thanks for reply!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

ascmd.exe is included in this [MS-SQL Server samples download](http://www.codeplex.com/SqlServerSamples/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=4000).  This is a different page than the one you probably went to originally, it has moved.  Just click on the SqlServerSamples.msi link.

Answer (score 3):

You will get with SP2 samples.

You can download and install it separately from http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=e719ecf7-9f46-4312-af89-6ad8702e4e6e&displaylang=en

Answer (score 0):

With MS AS 2005 you should have under "sample_inst\Analysis Services\Administrator\ascmd\CS".

where sample_inst is the folder where you have installed the samples

Typcally:

"C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\90\Samples"